# How to Get the longest match found in number of sets, order is important

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop

I need to find a way to return the longest match found in number of sets/lists (values returns only once) when the order of items is important.
the list is not cyclic.

A match is a sequence of values that exists in all the lists and maintains the same order of elements in all the lists.

e.g. 1:

```
    List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9 };
    List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 9 };
    List<int> list3 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9 };
    List<int> list4 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
```

result { 1, 2 }

e.g. 2:

```
     List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 6, 8, 1, 18 };
     List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 18, 19, 17, 14 };
     List<int> list3 = new List<int> { 2, 5, 6, 8, 1, 18, 16, 13, 14 };
     List<int> list4 = new List<int> { 2, 6, 8, 1, 18, 19, 17, 14 };
```

result { 6, 8, 1, 18 }

The match doesn't have to be found at the beginning or at the end and can be on any part of any list.

I hope that I explained my problem good enough :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please Note: SO is not a magic code writing service.

Comment: do you get the "I solve the interview-question on SO" badge for this? - What about Anonymous - will he get provision? ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a map from pairs of ints to a count of how many of the lists they appear adjacent in.

Pseudo-code:

```
For each list L {
    For each adjacent pair (x, y) in L {
         Counts[x, y] += 1
    }
}
```

Now you can iterate through the first list (or the shortest list), and find the longest run such that each adjacent pair (x, y) in the run with Counts[x, y] showing that the pair appears in every list.

Pseudo-code:

```
run = []
best_run = []
For x in L[0] {
    if len(run) is zero or Counts[run[len(run)-1], x] == number of lists {
        run = run + x
    } else {
        run = [x]
    }
    if run is longer than best_run {
        best_run = run
    }
}
```

This works given the assumption in the question that no integer appears twice in the same list.

This algorithm runs in O(N) time, where N is the sum of the lengths of all the lists.

Comment: great answer - I like that you did not give the final C# ;)

Comment: That's a great idea!! I didn't even though in that direction! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach.

First I need a way to compare lists:

```
public class ListCompare<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<T> left, List<T> right)
    {
        return left.SequenceEqual(right);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> list)
    {
        return list.Aggregate(0, (a, t) => a ^ t.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Next a method to produce all subsequences of a source list:

```
Func<List<int>, IEnumerable<List<int>>> subsequences = xs =>
    from s in Enumerable.Range(0, xs.Count)
    from t in Enumerable.Range(1, xs.Count - s)
    select xs.Skip(s).Take(t).ToList();
```

Now I can create a list of lists:

```
var lists = new [] { list1, list2, list3, list4, };
```

Finally a query that pulls it all together:

```
var answer =
    lists
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            subsequences(lists.First()),
            (a, l) => a.Intersect(subsequences(l), new ListCompare<int>()))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Given the sample data provided in the question this produces the expected results.

Comment: +1 - I think this is the brute-force one that would be the expected first answer - the sad part is that the OP seems to have lost all interest in working on this on his own

Comment: @CarstenKönig - I was actually a bit surprised how fast this was. I tried it with 20,000 lists and it computed the result in under 800ms. I think a lot of the time a brute force approach is worth trying and then worth trying to see what it takes to push it over the edge. In this case the OPs original data sets are completing in a few milliseconds.

Comment: I'm with you - it is a good/readable approach and if it is reasonable for the problem(size) than it's fine

Answer (score 0):

1. First generate an ordered combination of `int` from the shortest list
2. Compare the lists other than shortest list with the combination. For easy comparison of lists I just convert to `string` and use `string.Contains()`
3. Return immediately if find the match as the items left are next order or the shorter one.

---

```
public static List<int> GetLongestMatch(params List<int>[] all)
{
    var shortest = all.Where(i => i.Count == all.Select(j => j.Count).Min()).First();
    var permutations = (from length in Enumerable.Range(1, shortest.Count)
                        orderby length descending
                        from count in Enumerable.Range(1, shortest.Count - length + 1)
                        select shortest.Skip(count - 1).Take(length).ToList())
                        .ToList();

    Func<List<int>, string> stringfy = (list) => { return string.Join(",", list.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()); };
    foreach (var item in permutations)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", item.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()));
        if (all.All(list => stringfy(list).Contains(stringfy(item))))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Matched, skip process and return");
            return item;
        }
    }
    return new List<int>();
}
```

Usage

```
var result = GetLongestMatch(list1, list2, list3, list4);
```

Result

```
2, 3, 6, 8, 1, 18
2, 3, 6, 8, 1
3, 6, 8, 1, 18
2, 3, 6, 8
3, 6, 8, 1
6, 8, 1, 18
Matched, skip process and return
```